# What are the correct steps to re-deploy a docker container on compute engine?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-compute-engine

I deploy a docker container on compute engine.

I want to re-deploy this docker container after I build a new docker image with same image name and tag, like `webapp:latest`

For now, I re-deploy docker container by restart compute engine instance.

I think it's not correct.

What is the correct way for re-deploying a docker container?

Answer (score -2):

When you deploy Docker images on Google Compute Engine virtual machine instances there is some [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#limitations) as you can only deploy one container for each VM instance and you can only use Container-Optimized OS images with this deployment method.

I believe the best workaround is to uncheckbox the container option in your instance details to do not deploy a container to the VM instance by using a container-optimized OS image. This option is useful if you want to [deploy a single container](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#simple) on the VM.

[image]

Instead, install [docker](https://docs.docker.com/) in your VM outside the GCP. Also, Consider [Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) Engine if you need to deploy multiple containers per VM instance.